# Get inner html of div stored in var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm getting some data from a server, and it's coming down prepackaged in  elements. The issue is that there is a bunch of stuff in those tags that I don't want. Does anyone have any suggestions to get only the html of those elements? I have something that works, but it's hack-y and worse yet, it assumes that I know something about the attributes of the tags, and I won't always:

Here's some JQuery (see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/tPJau/):

```
$(function () {
    var rawString = "<div id='something' myAttr='somethingElse' > Free me!</div>";
    $('#content').append(rawString);
    var cleanString = $('#something').html();
    $('#something').remove();
    $('#content').append(cleanString);
});
```

And here's some html:

```
<div id="content">original content</div>
```

Which gives me

```
<div id='content'>
    original content Free me!
</div>
```

So my question to you, dear community, is how do I accomplish this #without# knowing anything about the div attributes?

Comment: You need to explain this a little better, but `myAttr` is not a valid attribute, and the `remove()` does nothing to the `cleanString` variable ?

Comment: you have to know something about the div attributes as you will select it based on the attribute.

Comment: It 'is' a valid attribute in the sense that you're free (as in speech, not beer) to use any attribute you want so long as it's properly formatted. It's just there for your enjoyment, and to make the point that things beyond my knowledge will be going on in the element. (eg. styles, other stuff that I wish wasn't there, etc)

Comment: It is **not** a valid attribute, it works but that does'nt make it valid HTML.

Comment: But then again, who said what version of HTML I'm using? Maybe I wrote my own standard (I didn't). Maybe the people serving up these elements like to embed name/value pairs with favorite foods for each of their cats in the tags. "it assumes that I know something about the attributes of the tags, and I won't always" It may not be valid HTML, but I'm not the one who's writing it. The point that I was trying to make is that you can assume nothing about anonymous input. It was simply meant to underscore my point, and looking at the answers, it doesn't look like it detracted from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass HTML into the JQuery function and it will create an element in memory.

You can then manipulate that element like any other element that physically exists in your page.

```
$(function () {
    var rawString = "<div id='something' myAttr='somethingElse' > Free me!</div>";
    var cleanString = $(rawString).html(); // ... or .text()
    $('#content').append(cleanString);
});
```

Comment: calling .html() on a variable seems to be the way to go. I'm accepting your answer because I believe you were the first to post one

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(function () {
    var rawString = "<div id='something' myAttr='somethingElse' > Free me!</div>";
    var node = $('#content');
    node.html(node.html() + $(rawString).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know its a `div` then;

```
 var cleanString = $('#content div').text();
```

Another option is to use;

```
var cleanString = $(rawString).text();
```

Comment: I'm not going to use your solution, but it works and it's clean and concise so I'm still voting it up

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're after is the content 'Free me!'.  You can extract that directly from the rawString variable with this: `$(rawString).html()`.  This is just wrapping that HTML with the jQuery function which allows you to grab the inner HTML of that element.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(function () {

    var rawString = "<div id='something' myAttr='somethingElse' > Free me!</div>";
    var rawHtml = $( rawString ).html();

    $('#content').append(        
        rawHtml
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex, if you want:

```
var rawString = "<div id='something' myAttr='somethingElse' > Free me!</div>";
var re = /<[^>]+>([^<]*)/;
var matches = rawString.match(re);

$('#content').append(matches[1]);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tPJau/4/

Comment: Vote up for doing it the "right" way, but I'm still going with scott.korin for simplicity's sake

Comment: Did anyone see where I set that jQuery magic hammer down at?